# How to get minimum single value with reference to other value greater than zero?

Tags: r, dataframe

Below is my sample data

```
df <- data.frame('a'=c(0.1,0.2,0.3,0.4,1.0,1.1,1.2,3.1,3.2),'b'=c(0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,100,120)))
```

I would like to see single value `3.1` as my output

Appreciate any help.

Comment: can you please explain the expectations bit more like how you want to drive output via given dataframe

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get corresponding value of `a` after first value greater than 0 in `b`, you could do

```
df$a[which.max(df$b > 0)]
#[1] 3.1
```

Or only with `which`

```
df$a[which(df$b > 0)[1]]
```

**data**

```
df <- data.frame(a=c(0.1,0.2,0.3,0.4,1.0,1.1,1.2,1.3,3.1,3.2),
                 b=c(0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,100,120))
```

Comment: @TusharLad Although I am confused if you want the above or `min(df$a[which(df$b > 0)])` ?

Comment: first answer works very fine @Ronak. as when value started increasing in b that time i want value of b

Comment: i have arrange my data based on oder so this works very fine.